# Explicit date/datetime cast

Tags: mysql, datetime, mysql-5.5

In the `BETWEEN` documentation description (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) I've noticed a weird expression that I cannot understand entirely:

> For best results when using BETWEEN with date or time values, use CAST() to explicitly convert the values to the desired data type. Examples: If you compare a DATETIME to two DATE values, convert the DATE values to DATETIME values. If you use a string constant such as '2001-1-1' in a comparison to a DATE, cast the string to a DATE.

So I have the following questions:

1. Could anyone provide an example when it's **really necessary** (with explanation of that) and when `cast` would change the result or performance dramatically. Let's assume we use one of number of date literals mysql defines (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-literals.html). For sake of simplicity let it be of `YYYY-MM-DD` (`'2013-07-26'`) format (with any date you like)
2. Could anyone clarify what "best results" mean? The result is either expected, or not - what is the "best" in this case?

PS: the target mysql version is the latest 5.5 available and newer.

PPS: to make things clear:

- The question assumes we use datetime/date compatible columns, not varchars etc
- The question is about expanding type, not about narrowing

Answer (score -1):

Look at simple example (MySql 5.6):

```
drop table dattes;
create table dattes(
   id  int,
   da_te  date,
   name varchar(200)
);

set @x = 0;
insert into dattes
select (@x:=@x+1),
       '2013-5-1' + interval @x day,
       t.column_name
from information_schema.columns t
;
```

and here is a query:

```
Set @start_date = cast( '2013-5-2' as date);
Set @start_datetime = cast( '2013-5-2 15:00' as datetime);
Set @end_date = cast( '2013-5-10' as date);

select   (Select sum( id ) from dattes
          where da_te between @start_date and @end_date) da_test1,

         (Select sum( id ) from dattes
          where da_te between @start_datetime and @end_date) da_test2,

         (Select sum( id ) from dattes
          where da_te between cast( @start_datetime as date) 
                and @end_date) da_test3
;
+ ------------- + ------------- + ------------- +
| da_test1      | da_test2      | da_test3      |
+ ------------- + ------------- + ------------- +
| 45            | 44            | 45            |
+ ------------- + ------------- + ------------- +
```

One would expect that in 2nd case MySql would implicitely convert @start_datetime to date (because the column da_te in the table is date) -> but MySql did the opposite, it widen other arguments to datetime. Because of this one record from the table was skipped ( '2013-5-2 00:00' < '2013-5-2 15:00').
This affects performance of course (maybe not dramatically, but a little), because MySql must convert all column values (or values of an index, if is any) from date to datetime.

Comment: "This affects performance of course because MySql must convert all column values (or values of an index, if is any) from date to datetime" --- this is not correct at all. Plus `cast( @start_datetime as date) ` please read the PPS part of the question: the question **IS NOT** about type narrowing. Sorry, but not an answer.

Comment: "Because of this one record from the table was skipped `( '2013-5-2 00:00' < '2013-5-2 15:00')`." --- and this is **EXPECTED** behaviour, because `00:00 < 15:00`

Comment: `cast( '2013-5-2 15:00' as datetime)` or `cast( '2013-5-2' as date)` - this doesn't make much sense. Without `cast()` it would work exactly the same.